# Calculate HSV histogram of a coloured image is it different from H-S histogram?

Tags: c++, opencv

I want to calculate HSV histogram of a image .I have searched it a lot but found nothing useful. In opencv online guide i found H-S histogram . what effect has V on illumination? Are HSV and H-S are same (means to say V has no effect on illumination)? here is the code for H-S histogram

```
cvtColor( Frame, hsv_base, CV_BGR2HSV );
    int h_bins = 50; 
int s_bins = 32;
int histSize[] = { h_bins, s_bins };

float h_ranges[] = { 0, 256 };
float s_ranges[] = { 0, 180 };

const float* ranges[] = { h_ranges, s_ranges };
int channels[] = { 0, 1 };
calcHist( &hsv_base, 1, channels, Mat(), hist_base, 2, histSize, ranges, true, false );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend you read the [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV) page about HSV.

But to give a quick answer the V component basically controls how bright is the color. So probably if the goal is to create a histogram of colors then you don't want to distinguish between dark green and light green.

To answer your question H-S only refers to the first two channels of the HSV image.
If you really want to cluster in 3 channels you could do that by modifying your code to act on 3 channels and adding a third dimension to your histogram. But this might not be what you want to achieve.

```
cvtColor( Frame, hsv_base, CV_BGR2HSV );
int h_bins = 50; 
int s_bins = 32;
int v_bins = 10;
int histSize[] = { h_bins, s_bins, v_bins };

float h_ranges[] = { 0, 180 };
float s_ranges[] = { 0, 256 };
float v_ranges[] = { 0, 256 };

const float* ranges[] = { h_ranges, s_ranges, v_ranges };
int channels[] = { 0, 1, 2};
calcHist( &hsv_base, 1, channels, Mat(), hist_base, 3, histSize, ranges, true, false );
```

Comment: This code is not working correct . it got crash give opencv error assertion failed in unknown function.

Comment: There is not much I can do for you, it works fine for me. Try to debug your problem.

Comment: btw h_ranges should be from 0-180 and not 0-256.
i.e.
float h_ranges[]={0,180};
float s_ranges[]={0,256};

Comment: the ranges should be Hue 0-179 and Sat 0-255 and Val 0-255

Comment: @CaptainFantastic According to the [OpenCV docs](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d8/dbc/tutorial_histogram_calculation.html), `the upper boundary is exclusive`. {0,256} and {0,180} are right.