# creating 3D histogram using 2D data (OpenCV?)

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I have data set 1 and 2. Those have 2D data.
For example,

Data1 : 
(x1, y1), (x2, y2), (x3, y3) .... (xn, yn)

Data2 : (x1', y1'), (x2', y2'), .... (xm', ym')

I'd like to compare them using histogram and Earth Mover's Distance(EMD) if possible.

Because I have 2D data, the data should be placed on 2D map, and the height of the histogram on 2D map has the frequency of the data, thus it should be 3D histogram I guess. Even though I success to create example to draw histogram and compare them using 1D data, I failed to try to change it to 2D data. How it works?

For example,

```
calcHist(&greyImg, 1, channel_numbers, Mat(), histogram1, 1, &number_bins, &channel_ranges);
```

This code makes tha Image's grayscale intensity(1D data) to histogram. But I could not change it to 2D data.

- my Idea is this : 
  I create cv::Mat Data1Mat, Data2Mat; (Mat size is set as maximum value of x and y)
  Then, push the Data1's x values to Mat1's first channel, push y values to second channel. (Same to Data2 and Data2Mat)
  For example, for (x1, y1), set

  ```
  Data1Mat.at(x1,y1)[0] = x1, Data1Mat.at(x1, y1)[1] = y1;
  ```

like this.Then create Histogram of them and compare. Do I think correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is more correct to say: histogram of 1D data, of histogram of 2D data.

You need histogram of 2D data.

- 1D histogram computes number of scalar values hit bin intervals.
- 2D histogram divides plane by regions and compute number of 2D points
  hit    each region.

Here computed H,S 2D histogram for an image: [Calculate HSV histogram of a coloured image is it different from H-S histogram?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20028933/calculate-hsv-histogram-of-a-coloured-image-is-it-different-from-h-s-histogram)

You have near the same problem, but put your x to instead of H, and y instead of S.